# Flink join operator after sorting seems to group fields (Scala)

Tags: scala, join, apache-flink

I have implemented a simple Scala object using Flink to play with joins operator. After that I put the join operator show my results I decided to sort the output by the first field. It seems that the output is ordered by group. The output shows two groups of "Fyodor Dostoyevsky". Why is this happening? How do I sort the complete DataSet?

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.Order
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.{ExecutionEnvironment, _}

object JoinBooksAndAuthors {
  val AUTHOR_ID_FIELD: Int = 0
  val AUTHOR_NAME_FIELD: Int = 1

  val BOOK_AUTHORID_FIELD: Int = 0
  val BOOK_YEAR_FIELD: Int = 1
  val BOOK_NAME_FIELD: Int = 2

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val authors = env.readCsvFile[(Int, String)](
      "downloads/authors.tsv",
      fieldDelimiter = "\t",
      lineDelimiter = "\n",
      includedFields = Array(0, 1)
    )

    val books = env.readCsvFile[(Int, Short, String)](
      "downloads/books.tsv",
      fieldDelimiter = "\t",
      lineDelimiter = "\n",
      includedFields = Array(0, 1, 2)
    )

    authors
      .join(books)
      .where(AUTHOR_ID_FIELD)
      .equalTo(BOOK_AUTHORID_FIELD)
      .map(tuple => (tuple._1._2, tuple._2._3))
      .sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING)
      .print()
  }
}
```

output

```
(Charles Bukowski,Women)
(Charles Bukowski,The Most Beautiful Woman in Town)
(Charles Bukowski,Hot Water Music)
(Charles Bukowski,Barfly)
(Charles Bukowski,Notes of a Dirty Old Man)
(Charles Bukowski,Ham on Rye)
(Fyodor Dostoyevsky,The Brothers Karamazov)
(Fyodor Dostoyevsky,The Double: A Petersburg Poem)
(Fyodor Dostoyevsky,Poor Folk)
(George Orwell,Coming Up for Air)
(George Orwell,Burmese Days)
(George Orwell,A Clergyman's Daughter)
(George Orwell,Down and Out in Paris and London)
(Albert Camus,The Plague)
(Fyodor Dostoyevsky,The Eternal Husband)
(Fyodor Dostoyevsky,The Gambler)
(Fyodor Dostoyevsky,The House of the Dead)
(Fyodor Dostoyevsky,Crime and Punishment)
(Fyodor Dostoyevsky,Netochka Nezvanova)
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Xingcanc helped me saying to use `.partitionByRange(0).sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING)` to sort globally rather than sorting locally